# why cellspacing is not supported in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cellspacing

I've a table with the following property set.

and the table is for the results of repeater control.

This works fine with IE7/older versions and am able to get a border for the table with the results displayed

But when try the same with the IE8, Cellspacing doesn't seem to have any effect and am not able to get the border around the table..

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the IE Team changed a few things in v8. More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533551(VS.85).aspx