# IE9 and cellspacing

Tags: html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

It appears to me that IE9 does not recognize cellspacing. Anybody noticed the same too?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use the CSS [`border-spacing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304069.aspx) attribute, anyway. Most browsers support it, Internet Explorer does since IE 8.

Comment: here is what I did:
`<table style="border-spacing:4px" .... >`

instead of:

`<table cellcpacing="4" ....>`


Both worked the same for chrome and ie9; and they worked as intended for chrome, but not for ie9 :(

Answer (score 1):

[Try using CSS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339923/how-to-set-cellpadding-cellspacing-in-css)

See also, [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721363/why-cellspacing-is-not-supported-in-ie8).

Answer (score 0):

IE9 ignores css border-spacing.  Use both css border-spacing and a redundant html cell-spacing attribute.